# Trivial change but different results (ForAll and Exists)

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a set of inequalities that I want to find a (trivial) solution.

When I use the **Exists** operator, everything works great, as you can see in this [Z3 script](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/WUMsl) and in its Z3Py version.

```
#!/bin/python

from z3 import *

# we have that
s = Solver()
## mu0_px is the initial marking for place px; 
mu_p1, mu_p2, mu_p3 = 0, 0, 1

## pi_tj is the pre-condition from place pi to transition tj
p1_t1, p1_t2, p1_t3 = 1, 0, 0
p2_t1, p2_t2, p2_t3 = 0, 1, 0
p3_t1, p3_t2, p3_t3 = 0, 0, 1

## tj_pi is the post-condition from transition tj to place pi
t1_p1, t2_p1, t3_p1 = 0, 1, 0
t1_p2, t2_p2, t3_p2 = 1, 0, 0
t1_p3, t2_p3, t3_p3 = 0, 0, 0

## find the values for the faulty transitions 
f_p1, p1_f = Ints('f_p1 p1_f')
f_p2, p2_f = Ints('f_p2 p2_f')
f_p3, p3_f = Ints('f_p3 p3_f')

# where they should be 
s.add( f_p1 == 1, f_p2 == 0, f_p3 == 0 )
s.add( p1_f == 0, p2_f == 0, p3_f == 1 )

## l \in Naturals ; 
l11 = Int('l11')

# Sequence 11: t1,t2,t3
s11_t1, s11_t2, s11_t3 = 1, 1, 0


# It does works! :o
s.add( l11 == 1 )
s.add(
   Exists([l11],
      Or(
         mu_p1 + (t1_p1-p1_t1)*s11_t1 + (t2_p1-p1_t2)*s11_t2 + (t3_p1-p1_t3)*s11_t3 + l11 * (f_p1 - p1_f) < p1_t3,
         mu_p2 + (t1_p2-p2_t1)*s11_t1 + (t2_p2-p2_t2)*s11_t2 + (t3_p2-p2_t3)*s11_t3 + l11 * (f_p2 - p2_f) < p2_t3,
         mu_p3 + (t1_p3-p3_t1)*s11_t1 + (t2_p3-p3_t2)*s11_t2 + (t3_p3-p3_t3)*s11_t3 + l11 * (f_p3 - p3_f) < p3_t3,
      )
   )
)


print(s)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

However, when I replace the existential quantifier by **Forall** as in this [link](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/2iZS), and in the Python code below, there is no solution when I believe that it should still be **sat**.

```
#!/bin/python

from z3 import *

# we have that
s = Solver()
## mu0_px is the initial marking for place px; 
mu_p1, mu_p2, mu_p3 = 0, 0, 1

## pi_tj is the pre-condition from place pi to transition tj
p1_t1, p1_t2, p1_t3 = 1, 0, 0
p2_t1, p2_t2, p2_t3 = 0, 1, 0
p3_t1, p3_t2, p3_t3 = 0, 0, 1

## tj_pi is the post-condition from transition tj to place pi
t1_p1, t2_p1, t3_p1 = 0, 1, 0
t1_p2, t2_p2, t3_p2 = 1, 0, 0
t1_p3, t2_p3, t3_p3 = 0, 0, 0

## find the values for the faulty transitions 
f_p1, p1_f = Ints('f_p1 p1_f')
f_p2, p2_f = Ints('f_p2 p2_f')
f_p3, p3_f = Ints('f_p3 p3_f')

# where they should be 
s.add( f_p1 == 1, f_p2 == 0, f_p3 == 0 )
s.add( p1_f == 0, p2_f == 0, p3_f == 1 )

## l \in Naturals ; 
l11 = Int('l11')

# Sequence 11: t1,t2,t3
s11_t1, s11_t2, s11_t3 = 1, 1, 0


# It does not work! :(
s.add( l11 == 1 )
s.add(
   ForAll([l11],
      Or(
         mu_p1 + (t1_p1-p1_t1)*s11_t1 + (t2_p1-p1_t2)*s11_t2 + (t3_p1-p1_t3)*s11_t3 + l11 * (f_p1 - p1_f) < p1_t3,
         mu_p2 + (t1_p2-p2_t1)*s11_t1 + (t2_p2-p2_t2)*s11_t2 + (t3_p2-p2_t3)*s11_t3 + l11 * (f_p2 - p2_f) < p2_t3,
         mu_p3 + (t1_p3-p3_t1)*s11_t1 + (t2_p3-p3_t2)*s11_t2 + (t3_p3-p3_t3)*s11_t3 + l11 * (f_p3 - p3_f) < p3_t3,
      )
   )
)


print(s)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Did anyone ever have a problem like this before?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `l11` as you declared and the one that gets used in the quantification are totally different: In particular, you stating it equals 1 have no bearing in the quantified formula. So you get `sat` with existential but `unsat` with universal since the formula is clearly not true for all values of `l11`.

This might be confusing, but it is the intended behaviour. To see the effect, simply print the smtlib equivalent and you’ll see how the variables are assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @alias

And how can I express a constraint saying that I want a solution `ForAll l11 >= 1`?

I changed the code as in the URL below, but I'm still wondering if this is the right way to express such a constraint within a universal quantifier.

https://gist.github.com/damascenodiego/d66b8d53ccda58dc389141e213cadb27

Comment: Just write it like you said it (modulo syntax:) `ForAll ([l1], Implies (l1 >= 1, condition))`

Comment: Thanks for the help @alias